# extract url from a hyperlinked string in PHP

Tags: php, urls

I need a function to extract the link (url) from a hyperlinked text in PHP.
For example i get it a string and it returns me the link or url.

Thanks before for your answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr_str = new SimpleXMLElement('<a href="www.example.com">Click here</a>');
echo $arr_str['href']; // will echo www.example.com
```

Note that, [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) required PHP version above 5.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's perfect but I have this warning: Warning: Illegal string offset 'href' in url...